# Converting from switch-case to if-then statement

Tags: shell, csh

I am trying validate input using cshell but am having trouble with the exact syntax. I know what you can use switch case structures like so:

```
switch ( $input )
  case [0-9]:
     echo Input is good
```

But is there a way to do this with if-then statements? I know that the easiest solution is to stop using a terrible scripting language, but I'd appreciate it if someone could give me the answer with csh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My csh skills are a bit dated, but I believe the syntax you're looking for is:

```
if ($input =~ [0-9]) then
    echo "Input is good"
endif
```

The only reason I'd use csh over, say bash, or even sh for a script is because I had to maintain an existing script and wasn't permitted to rewrite it, or it had to be sourced into a c shell environment. (And there are ways around that last if you're determined.)